# how to load resource file while running python unittest using twisted trial

Tags: python, twisted, python-unittest, trial, pkg-resources

**Problem**

As part of python unittest, some input json files are to be loaded which exists under 'data' directory which resides in the same directory of test py file.

'pkg_resources' is used for this purpose.

It works fine when the unittest are running with python. But it fails when running with twisted trial.

My project has mixed testcases with both python unittest testcases as well as twisted.trial.unittest testcases. so, there is a need to run both type of testcases with twisted trial in general.

The '_trial_temp' directory is added in path when running testcases with twisted trial. please, let me know there is any way to handle this?

**Example directory structure:**

```
myproject/
└── tests
    ├── data
    │   └── input.json
    ├── trialTest.py
```

**trialTest.py**

```
import unittest
import inspect
import pkg_resources

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_01_pathTest(self):
        dataDirExists =     pkg_resources.resource_exists(inspect.getmodule(self).__name__, 'data')
        print 'data exists: %s' % (dataDirExists)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

**Running test using python and its output:**

```
cd myproject
python tests/trialTest.py
data exists: True
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

**Running test using python and its output:**

```
cd myproject
/usr/local/bin/trial tests/trialTest.py
trialTest
  Test
    test_01_pathTest ... data exists: False
                                                  [OK]

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 tests in 0.013s

PASSED (successes=1)
```

Comment: What is the return value of `inspect.getmodule(self)` in these two cases?

Comment: python: <module '__main__' from 'tests/trialTest.py'>,   trial: <module 'trialTest' from 'tests/trialTest.pyc'>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first example, `__name__` will be set to `__main__`, and the `tests` directory will be automatically added to `sys.path`.  This works more or less by accident; if you move your `unittest.main` invocation to another module, you won't be able to import it quite the same way, and `data` may not show up.

In the second example, `trial` will, depending on the presence of an `__init__.py` file in the `tests` directory, set `__name__` to either `trialTest` or `tests.trialTest`; or perhaps even `myproject.tests.trialTest`.

You should re-name the module to `test_trialtest.py` so that it is discovered by trial's module-walking code properly, and then invoke it with a *module* name rather than a file name.  This means you should have a clear idea of what `myproject/tests/test_trialtest.py`'s module name is *supposed* to be.  Is `myproject` supposed to be on `sys.path`?  The parent directory?

Basically, `pkg_resources` depends intimately on the details of the namespaces into which code is loaded and executed, so you need to be careful that everything is set up consistently.  If you make sure that everything is imported the same way, under the same name (never as `__main__`, for example) then this should be totally consistent between `trial` and stdlib `unittest`; there's nothing really special about trial here except that you are running it (`trial` itself)` as the main script rather than your test script as the main script.

Comment: Thanks. As you have mentioned, Touching an __init__.py file inside tests directory resolves this issue.

Answer (score -1):

place an `__init__.py` in tests directory resolves the issue.

```
[durai@localhost myproject]$ touch tests/__init__.py
[durai@localhost myproject]$ tree
.
├── tests
    ├── data
    │   └── input.json
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── trialTest.py
    └── trialTest.pyc

[durai@localhost myproject]$ trial tests/trialTest.py
tests.trialTest
  Test
    test_01_pathTest ... currModule: <module 'tests.trialTest' from '/home/durai/Worskspace/myproject/tests/trialTest.pyc'>
currModule: tests.trialTest
data exists: True
                                                  [OK]

------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -
Ran 1 tests in 0.016s

PASSED (successes=1)
```